# R- plyr to parallelize

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plyr

I need to parallelize a probabilistic neural network calculus. Since I need a progress bar, I was told to use plyr instead of %dopar% and foreach.

Let's assume my table is:

```
tra<-data.frame(flag_compro=c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0), a=c(0.3,0.4, 0.2, 0.1,.04, .9, .2), b=c(.3, .6, .7, .6, .8, .9, .1))
```

the "training" although a pnn just memorizes the structure:

```
library("pnn")
pnn <- learn(tra, category.column=grep('flag_compro', colnames(tra)))
nn1 <- smooth(pnn, sigma=0.05)
```

then my function is:

```
pred_pnn <- function(x){
  data.frame(prob = guess(nn1, x)$probabilities[1], row.names = NULL)
}
```

Let's assume I'm predicting in another table (I will use the same for simplicity):

```
test<-tra[, -grep('flag_compro', colnames(tra))]
```

Now, I know that PNN package works for one row at a time. So the following does work:

```
pred_pnn(as.matrix(test)[1,])
```

So, if I try to use plyr package, with:

```
t<-as.matrix(test)
mlply(t, 1,pred_pnn, .parallel=T, .paropts=c('pnn'))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in do.ply(i) : 
  task 1 failed - "object pred_pnn not found"
In addition: Warning messages:
1: <anonymous>: ... may be used in an incorrect context: ‘.fun(piece, ...)’
```

I guess this is happening because I need to introduce a column name (?), but since I need to do it row by row how can I solve it?
Also how can I add a progress bar (or something that gives me an idea of the time left)?

Thanks

Comment: Read the documentation and use the `.paropts` argument.

Comment: I've just noticed your edit. That's not what the documentation tells you. You should probably also read the `foreach` vignette.

Comment: ok, I don't understand the documentation. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: `foreach` has a `.packages` argument. The plyr docs tell you to supply `foreach` arguments in a `list` to `.paropts`.

Comment: mlply(t,1, pred_pnn, .parallel=T, .paropts=c(.packages='pnn'))... and I get another error (error in task 1. "must be a string or a function").... plus I don't get what is the error meaning.. Should I pass the function also there?

Comment: `c()` does not create a list; use `list()`: `.paropts=list(.packages='pnn')`

Comment: I believe that the progress bar is disabled when plyr runs in parallel. I get the message "Progress disabled for parallel processing" when attempting to use a progress bar with `.parallel=TRUE`.